# Failing to pass a downloaded file-like object from sharepoint using the shareplum and paramiko libraries

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko, shareplum

I'm receiving an error when passing a file object using paramiko's putfo().

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'

Here's what my putfo() looks like

```
ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=host, port=port, username=username,password=password, look_for_keys=False)

ftp = ssh_client.open_sftp()

ftp.putfo(file_obj, remotepath=file_name)
```

`file_obj` is downloaded to memory using shareplum's get_file()

I'm unfamiliar what I should try here to solve this problem.

Comment: possibly pass a `BytesIO(file_obj)` to `putfo`

Comment: @AsishM. thanks for the suggestion, tried it and receiving the same error

Comment: can you add a section that shows the full traceback with `BytesIO`?

Comment: @AsishM. I'm so sorry, I just didn't save the changes when I wrapped it in the ```BytesIO()```. Works like a charm, thank you! Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Then your `file_obj` is not file-like object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`putfo` requires a file or file-like object. The error message indicates you're getting raw bytes instead of a file io (raw bytes don't have a `read` method, but file-io objects do).

To address that, wrap your returned bytes using `io.BytesIO`

```py
from io import BytesIO
ftp.putfo(BytesIO(file_obj), remotepath=file_name)
```

Comment: If SharePlum does not support real file-like object (a stream), and you have to deal with the data in a byte array, as suggested in this answer, then beware that the file has to completely fit into memory. And that and means that the file has to first completely download and only then the upload can start (again that won't be the case, if you have read file-like object).